# Are rated cable ampacities per conductor or per circuit?

Tags: current, ampacity

I'd like to construct a cable using connectors DigiKey 708-1190-ND to connect a 20A LED to its power supply. The connector is rated "32A". In this example the connector's third pin will not be connected to anything.

Is this connector:

(A) Safe, because the circuit current is 20A which is lower than 32A, or

(B) Unsafe, because a total of 40A is passing through the connector, which is higher than 32A.

Likewise, suppose I'd like to use a 4 pin connector to power two circuits each with 2.8A current. Do I need a cable/connector rated 2.8A, 2*2.8A, or or 4*2.8A?

Comment: Usually it specifies per pin, but not in this case. Usually it's per pin so you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is safe. Each power pole is rated for the 32A.

Note how the 10 pole connector only has a 10A rating at 250VAC/DC (it is effectively derated).